# causing Loop error

Tags: loops, fstream

I'm writting a simple Programm and I think I have a problem whith a loop.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<cmath>
#include<algorithm>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;





int main()
{
ifstream einlesen("Probearray.dat");//reading Data(1 2 3 ...) and control if opens
if(einlesen)
{
cout<<"Daten wurden geoffnet"<<endl;
}
else
{
cout<<"Daten wurden nicht geoffnet"<<endl;
return 99;
}


int x,n,a;
while (einlesen>>x)n++;//writing Data on int x and count blocks
{
einlesen.clear();
einlesen.seekg(0, ios_base::beg);
vector<int> vec1(n);
for (a=0; a<n; a++) //writing Data on a vector vec1 with size a
    {
    einlesen>>vec1.at(a); 

    cout<<vec1[0]<<endl;
    }
    }
```

I wanted to check if this simple loop did work, and it does show me the first number but the programm doesn't stop so I suggest something is wrong with the loop. There is no specific error so I don't know what to do?
Do you have any idea?

Comment: I am not really expeirenced with this, but it seems like oyu are missing a `}` to close the `while`.

Comment: Sorry I have the other  } forgotten to copy...